# @nuxtjs/pwa does not generate sw.js with local system hosts information

Tags: configuration, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js, hostname

I would like to apply PWA in nuxt(`@2.3.4`) web application.
The operating system is `OSX` latest.
So I have installed `@nuxtjs/pwa` and add some config to `nuxt.config.js`.

These are what I have added

```
module.exports = {
    ...

    modules: [
        ['@nuxtjs/pwa', {icon : false}]
    ],

    workbox : {
        dev: true,
        debug: true
    },

    manifest : {
        viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
        theme_color: '#3B8070'
    },
    ...
}
```

And build with `NODE_ENV=production` and start.

I am able to find `sw.js` in `localhost:9000`, but it is not available with
`local.jy.net:9000`.

I was expecting the same result since I register that hostname on my `hosts` file.

Here is what I have in `/private/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
127.0.0.1   Juneui-MacBook-Pro.local
127.0.0.1       local.jy.net aad901eb546340cc9a69b0b030b124fc.jy.net
```

How could I make `@nuxtjs/pwa` refers system hosts variables?

If you need more information, add reply then I will provide as possible as I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@nuxtjs/pwa` package is looking for the `build.publicPath` option: https://github.com/nuxt-community/pwa-module/blob/9f27d5cdae0e0341d6d4b4f6814f91db6eab1432/packages/manifest/index.js#L24

Adding this option to your `nuxt.config.js` should do the trick:

```
module.exports = {
   ...

   modules: [
      ['@nuxtjs/pwa', {icon : false}]
   ],

   workbox : {
      dev: true,
      debug: true
   },

   manifest : {
      viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
      theme_color: '#3B8070'
   },

   build: {
     publicPath: '//local.jy.net:9000/pwa/',
   }
   ...
}
```

You can find more information about the `publicPath` property here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#publicpath

Comment: I did not put `publicPath`. But it works in `production` build. In `development` build, it works in `localhost`, but does not referrs host system's `hosts` file.